# Database relations and constraints handled in application software

Tags: design, architecture, database, database-design, architectural-patterns

I've been working in an app that handles relations and constraints in application level.

How would this affect changing databases while keeping the application software?
This would mean the database would just be 'Data persistance as a service'.
How would this affect decoupling, modularity and orthogonality?

Comment: see [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broadly speaking, domain models require both constraints and transactions to keep them sound as they are updated.  (Sure some domain models are too simple to require these, but many are not.)  These constraints can be applied by code anywhere, typically either in or by the database, a service, or an application.  What we don't want is raw persistence exposed without the appropriate constraints and transactions of the domain model.

So, if the constraints and transactions are applied within the database, the database can be shared across multiple services and applications.

However, if the constraints are applied in a service, then the service can be shared by other services and by applications, but it would be unwise to share the database directly.

One could make a case for sharing the database in a read-only manner, but since part of the domain model logic is being handled by the service this can be error-prone.  For example, let's say that the database is a simple persistence mechanism, and does not offer constraints or transactions.  We can have a service that wraps this database; the service is intended to be shared, and, the service offers constraints and transactions.

If the database wrapping service is bypassed — even for read-only purposes — the reader may see inconsistent state, which is to say if a single transaction requires several writes, the reader may see one of those writes without seeing all of them.  The model should only be visible in between whole transactions, not within an ongoing transaction, as that would expose false model state.

As you can imagine, if the domain model's constraints are applied by the application, then the application can be shared (i.e. it can expose services) but the database probably should not.  Two different applications accessing the same database would need to would need to apply the same constraint logic, which makes for wet (vs. DRY) code.  Even more problematic is transactions when two different applications are accessing the same underlying, unprotected storage; the two applications will need to coordinate with each other, perhaps by using the operating system's file locking features.  Again, there is wet vs. DRY code if both applications have the appropriate coordination.  One can address some of that by putting the code in a library to use by both applications, but there remains the issue of bug fixes and potential requirement for coordinated roll out.

Generally speaking, you're best bet is to wrap unprotected persistence within a single service, which is then the point that supports sharing.  A SQL database pretty much is that service, assuming one appropriately uses its constraints and transactions; SQL doesn't expose the underlying, unprotected persistence.

Comment: Yes, RDBMSs are some of the most powerful pieces of software infrastructure ever invented. They are *super* cool for manymanymany purposes, even if current zeitgeist is suggesting otherwise. Use their capabilities.